# Giving a margin to my hyperlink image is creating a secondary hyperlink area how do I solve this?

Tags: html, css

this is how it looks when I use pestiside

[image]

I am using  `<a href ="Source"><img = "source"></a>` while I give the margin in a separate css folder and this is the code I use in it`.img{ margin = 20px }`

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a `display: inline-block;` on the a-element (hyperlink) and your problem should be fixed.